# How to implement import/export a file functionality in spring MVC framework

Tags: java, javascript, html, spring-mvc, import

I am working on functionality where I have to import a csv file in my web application.I am using following code for this:

```
<input name="file1" type="file" id="fileid" />   
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Import File" onclick='importTestSet( document.getElementById("fileid").value)' />
```

However the above code only returns the file name instead of the full path of the file.I searched on other forums and found that this is happening due to security reasons of the browser.

1) Is there any other way to get the full path of the file while importing

2) Could you please help me with some sample code to implement this feature in spring MVC framework web application project.

Comment: From your description it looks like you are trying to upload a file from browser. Is that so?

Comment: yes.Current functionality is through browser but it will be great if there is any other way to implement this

Comment: http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/08/spring-mvc-file-upload-example.html and http://www.journaldev.com/2573/spring-mvc-file-upload-example-tutorial-single-and-multiple-files are examples of file(s) uploading

Comment: Have a look at the step-by-step example of file upload: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-file-upload-example/

Comment: But it takes only the file name and not the filepath.For importing a file i need the full file path of the file!

Answer (score 0):

You should copy that file on temporary folder
so when you can upload file at that time copy file method is called 
and put this method in input tag 
`<input type"file" onChange="copyFile()" />`
then you have to path of this file.